# Java Base64 encoding of Excel File missing last byte

Tags: java, base64, nio

I am base64 encoding an excel file, send it somewhere where it is saved. Apparently after this, excel complains that the file is incorrect and if I want to attept a restore. The code I am doing (actually I did a quick test main method) is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\VariousJunk\\excel-test", "test.xlsx");

    ByteArrayOutputStream base64StringOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream base64EncodingStream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(base64StringOutputStream);
    Files.copy(p, base64EncodingStream);
    base64StringOutputStream.close();
    String b64 = base64StringOutputStream.toString();

    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\VariousJunk\\excel-test\\test-backup.xlsx");
    fos.write(data);
    fos.close();
}
```

Now I have compared binary data of both files and it appears, that the output file is only missing one last byte with value 0. I have added the last bit for the test

```
fos.write(data);
fos.write(0);
fos.close();
```

And it works fine. The problem is I will be using this for any other type of data, and so I am not sure whether hardcoding a last byte is a good idea, possibly it might crash other filetypes. Is this a feature of this Base64 encoding method or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [From the API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap(java.io.OutputStream)) - probably need to `base64StringOutputStream.close()` before `base64StringOutputStream.toString()`.

Comment: @AndrewS I have modified the example above to add close, but still missing last byte

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the missing bit was base64EncodingStream.close() just after Files.copy()

```
    OutputStream base64EncodingStream = Base64.getEncoder().wrap(base64StringOutputStream);
    Files.copy(p, base64EncodingStream);
    base64EncodingStream.close();

    String b64 = base64StringOutputStream.toString();
```